# iMac stuck in first aid unresponsive

Tags: disk-utility, catalina, imac

I am helping out a friend with his iMac. It got ridiculously slow so we backed up his photo library (which was over 800GB) and deleted it.

He has 2018 iMac 21" with a 1TB SSD, running OSX Catalina 10.15.7

I then tried to run a first aid via Disk Utility but it has been stuck on 'verifying the start up volume will cause the computer to stop responding' and the progress bar is on 'running...' it has been like this for the past 18 hours. The bar at the top with the Apple logo is gone.

I can't 'force quit' because the computer is unresponsive, but the mouse is still able to move around.

What can I do??

[image: Photo of First Aid in progress]